# Method render() is not being called when custom Laravel exception is thrown from view composer

Tags: laravel, exception, eloquent

**Edited:**
I have a custom exception with render method which is being called when I throw it e.g. from controller, but not being called when I throw it in View composer.

So when I do something like that

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

and put dd() to exception render method

```
public function render()
{
    dd('render is called');
}
```

I get no result.

If I log my exception directly, finds out that first the CustomException being thrown, then as the result I see ErrorException.

I found a place where it being thrown.

\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::handleViewException

```
protected function handleViewException(Exception $e, $obLevel)
{
    $e = new ErrorException($this->getMessage($e), 0, 1, $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e);

    parent::handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
}
```

I didn't found any mentions in Laravel docs about that case. 
I found a tread on github with the same issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24658

So the question is, is this expected? Is there any adequate way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: so you access `$model->foo` and what happens?

Comment: @lagbox if I log my exception directly, finds out that first the CustomException being thrown, then as the result I see ErrorException. I'm not really familiar with the logic in Pipeline, but somehow it gets previous custom exception from session and then covers it with ErrorException. The ErrorException is being handled by Handler tho. Please feel free to ask more specific question so I can share necessary info.

Comment: Exception in view rendering are catched and never reach the handler as is. they are intercepted. Laravel does that to give proper error reporting (reports the error in the blade instead of the compiled php file in /storage/framework/views/xx.php file)

Comment: @N69S I see. I tried to change the behaviour of CompilerEngine a bit in order to not catch some types of exceptions where I need to apply my processing. Sounds not really great, but I don't see any other way in the scope of my needs. I want to throw other exception (let's say ViewCustomException) instead of ErrorException (please, see code from CompilerEngine I've mentioned in question), and it leads to multiple throwed ViewCustomException exceptions. If you aware of the logic applied in Laravel View rendering, could you please advise why is this happening?

Comment: Provided you a solution in my answer @mom__66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found working solution for myself. 
I've extended CompilerEngine and added additional processing in order to not throw ErrorException when I don't want to. 
The important thing is - your resulting Exception must be inherited from ErrorException. Otherwise you will face multiple calls to `\App\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::handleViewException` which can break your logic and write multiple log entities to your log file.

Comment: You modified the core laravel files ?

Comment: @N69S No, I've created custom ViewServiceProvider and registered my extended CompilerEngine there. I didn't remove ErrorException logic completely, only added extra processing for my exceptions to not break core logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

So, as you know, any exception during view compilation is intercepted and rethrown as `ErrorException` or as `FatalThrowableError`.

What you can do is intercept `ErrorException` and check `if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof \CustomException)` if so, you do your code, else, let the handler continue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck. Seems like method render() in Handler not being called either.

Comment: This not gonna work always. The behaviour I've described in comments shows that the parent of ErrorException will be ErrorException. I don't know how exactly it's happening, but it goes to \Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::handleViewException several times each time with ErrorException (except the very first time of course) so in the end parent will be ErrorException. Actually I'm not sure it's still easy to follow... Maybe I need to close the question.

Comment: you're only clean solution would be to not throw an exception in the render pipeline but beforehand in the controller (which is best practice)

Comment: It's not possible in my case. Also I need global handling (as Handler provides). I've posted the final solution that works for me fine  - @N69S